yml error in spring + postgres + jpa setup
i was setting up my project with application.yml and it didn't work.
it popped an psqlexception that said:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ġ��������: ����� "postgres"�� password ������ �����߽��ϴ�

my .yml file was like this:
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/board
        username: postgres
        password: 0000
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        database: postgresql
        hibernate:
             ddl-auto: create

then i made application.properties file with an exact same properties as .yml file and it worked.
.properties file was like this:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/board
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=0000
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

and i can't understand why it doesn't work with .yml when .properties does work.
as i googled my problem and there wasn't many results i think my problem is not that big, but i can't find out what is wrong so help me please sorry for bad english

Have you tried to enquote the strings like that: url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/board"?

do u have the error with stack trace ?

omg it worked thank you! a lot of examples in the web didn't enquote the string so i didn't think about that.

You don't have to enquote with .properites, but for YAML a colon is recognized as separator for node or leaf. And although you can get away in many cases without quotes, it's always better to use them for strings, at least when the strings contain more than one word or special characters.
